# Access update fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently writing a database for inventory of my home based computer business, and seem to be having some trouble. My question is:

Can Microsoft Access update fields on a form based off of results from a selection in a combo box, but still have the updated fields editable? And if so, how do I do this?

Example:

Table 1 (named Defaults) has the fields "Name", "Processor Speed", "Memory Size" and "Hard Drive Size". This holds "defaults" of what those values should be for each "Name".

Example:

Dell OptiPlex 520, 2000MHz, 1GB, and 80GB.

Dell OptiPlex 620, 2200MHz, 1.5GB, and 120GB.
etc.

The form is inputting data into a second table called "Inventory". The form has a list of names to select, and spots to fill out the processor speed, memory size, and hard drive size, among other things like serial numbers, installed software, date last worked on, and such.

When I select "Dell OptiPlex 520" from a dropdown box, I want the form to update the text fields with the defaults for it, but those fields still need to be changeable (such as if there is 2GB of memory installed) to record into the second table, which is where I run reports and such off of.

I have this currently working on an Excel spreadsheet using VLOOKUP to update values as I change the name, but I am not sure how to make this concept work in Access. I have tried using the DLOOKUP command, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. It is very possible I am not using it correctly.

I think this would have something to do with the "After Update" property on the combo box, then having some VBA code look at the "Name" field on the form, retrieve the values associated with that name from the "Defaults" table, and write them into the other text boxes on the form, but I am still not sure quite how to make this happen.

Thanks in advance for any help given in this aspect!

Comment: Important is if you want that the new value which you want to type will then be a choice for the future in this combo box or if you want that the choices in the combo box are limited but you can add other information to your inventory table. The answer to this question will decide how your tables should be designed. Maybe tell us your tables and fields for better understanding.

Comment: @Edgar No, I just want them to be "default" values. For example, if I select "Dell OptiPlex 520" in the combo box on the form, then it puts 2000MHz in the Processor Speed field, 1GB in the Memory field, and 80GB in the Hard Drive Size field. If I changed the Hard Drive Size field on the form to 100GB, it would save in the Inventory table as 100GB, but would not change the Defaults table, so that the next time I select Dell OptiPlex 520 in the combo box on the next record, the 2000MHz, 1GB, and 80GB would again, automatically fill in the fields of the form.

Comment: If I was to change the Dell OptiPlex 520 on the form to Dell OptiPlex 620, then the fields on the form would change to 2200MHz, 1.5GB, and 120GB respectively. The combo box is called "ComboName" and the fields on the form are called "ProcSpeed, MemSize, HDSize I believe this could be done though some VBA coding through Access with something like:
Private Sub ComboName_AfterUpdate()

Comment: If I was to change the Dell OptiPlex 520 in the combo box on the form to Dell OptiPlex 620, then the fields on the form would change to 2200MHz, 1.5GB, and 120GB respectively. The combo box is called "ComboName" and the fields on the form are called "ProcSpeed, MemSize, HDSize.

Comment: I believe this could be done though some VBA coding through Access with the following logic: Look up the "ComboName" value (on the form) and match it to the "Name" column in table "Default". Take the values from that row of the table "Default" which are named "Processor Speed", "Memory Size" and "Hard Drive Size", and input them into the form in the "ProcSpeed", "MemSize", "HDSize" fields respectively. Do this whenever ComboName is updated.
I think this could be done with VBA programming on the Private Sub ComboName_AfterUpdate(), but I do not know how to write the code specifically.

Comment: @Edgar - Thanks! That was very helpful. I appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the HowTo:

1. Create a table t_DefaultPCs with the following fields: PcType, Speed, Ram, HDD
2. Crate another table t_Inventory  with similar fields plus an ID field like i.e. your inventory number: InventoryId,  PcType, Speed, Ram, HDD
3. Create a query ql_DefaultPCs: SELECT t_DefaultPCs.PcType, t_DefaultPCs.Speed, t_DefaultPCs.Ram, t_DefaultPCs.HDD FROM t_DefaultPCs ORDER BY t_DefaultPCs.PcType;
4. Create a form with the form wizard based on the table Inventory: select table inventory, form wizard, all fields, finish
5. Add to this form a combo box. Call that combobox ComboDefaultPCs and change the following properties: RowSource: ql_DefaultPCs, Column Count: 4, Column Width: 4cm;2cm;2cm;2cm
6. Add the following code:

   `Private Sub ComboDefaultPCs_Click()
       PcType = ComboDefaultPCs.Column(0)
       Speed = ComboDefaultPCs.Column(1)
       Ram = ComboDefaultPCs.Column(2)
       HDD = ComboDefaultPCs.Column(3)
   End Sub`

You still have to write yourself the code to create new records in the inventory table and save the records. You can select one of your Default PCs in the combo box and it will fill out the fields of the inventory table. You can overwrite all these fields and it will not change your default values.

[image]